# websocat & Flask-SocketIO version compatibility

Tags: python, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

My SocketIO server is a Flask server listening on port 1234 with self-signed certs using v5.3.4 of `flask-SocketIO`. I am trying to connect to it using `websocat 1.11.0` using the command

```
websocat wss://localhost:1234/socket.io/?transport=websocket -k
```

However, the server reports the error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/May/2023 22:04:16] "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket HTTP/1.1" 400 -
The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols
```

and `websocat` client reports

```
websocat: WebSocketError: WebSocketError: Received unexpected status code (400 Bad Request)
websocat: error running
```

Is there a way to let `websocat` use a newer version of SocketIO protocol? Or an alternative to `websocat` that can use the newer SocketIO protocol?

**pip packages:**

- Flask-SocketIO==5.3.4
- python-socketio==5.8.0
- simple-websocket==0.10.0
- websockets==10.4

Comment: Does this client support the socket.io protocol at all? It looks like it is a plain websocket client, no reference to socket.io in their readme page.